# C++ function calling does not work

Tags: c++, function

In the following code:
.the return value may be off,
.the main problem is that I get an error were it wont call correctly if you need the exact error just comment say and I will
also in the other functions what return is needed

```
int menu()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "1 for gamemodes 2 for class editor (class editor not yet   
    made coming soon)" << endl;                           
    system("pause>nul");

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
    {
        gamemodes();
    }
    return 0;
}

int gamemodes()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "pick a gamemode" << endl;
    cout << "1 for team death match" << endl;
    cout << "rest coming soon!!!!" << endl;
    system("pause>nul");

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
    {
        map_picker();
    }
    return 0;
}

int map_picker()
{
    while (go = true)
    { 
        system("cls");
        cout << "pick a map" << endl;
        cout << "1 for town" << endl;
        system("pause>nul");

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
        {
            town_load();
        }
        return 0;
}

int town_load()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the error that needs to be fixed:

```
 'gamemodes': identifier not found,
```

updates any updates to this code will be placed in quotes here
"if I were to declare them before main would they execute / be used before being called"

Comment: I was going to fix your code formatting so it is indented (to make it readable) but you appear to be missing a `}` in `map_picker()`

Comment: i fixed that but i still get the original error

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `gamemodes` before using it in `main`. Add the declaration before `main`.

```
int gamemodes();

int main()
{
   ...
}
```

---

**Response to OP's comment**

The declaration

```
int gamemodes();
```

does not result in a function call. The declaration is there to allow the function to be used.

The function will be called in `main` in the block of you code you have:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
{
   // This is where the function gets called.
   gamemodes();
}
```

Comment: how do i stop it from executing them if there before they need to be used

Comment: @lucifer936, I don't follow your question.

Comment: @R Sahu i mean the compiler using them before they need to be.

Comment: @lucifer936, a declaration of the function will not affect your execution.

Comment: @R Sahu i will try this and if it works i will approve of your answer

Comment: @R Sahu what return value should be used

Comment: @lucifer936, I don't want to help you debug your program in SO comments.

Comment: @R Sahu ik i just cant find much in returning i am fairly new in c++ like a month in

Comment: @ R Sahu im about ready to close this page im doing it tomorrow

Comment: @lucifer936, I understand. SO is not a good place to learn the basics of the language. A textbook is much better for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is number of undeclared variables and functions in your original example.

When you declare a function after the `main function` and then try to use it in this `main function`, you  need to define a function prototype which is declaration as a function that specifies the function's name and type signature

So for your code:

you need to add the code for the function `GetAsyncKeyState`  or the prototype first and then the code later for that function.

Same thing as for the function `int gamemodes()` and for `map_picker()`

You have to declare the `go` boolean variable and `VK_NUMPAD1` variable as well

You have to add the main function too

Here is a code without compilation errors; but you have to add the code for your different functions that you use in your code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int town_load();

int gamemodes();

int VK_NUMPAD1 = 1;

bool go = true;

int map_picker();

int GetAsyncKeyState(int VK_NUMPAD1) {
    return 1;
}

int menu()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "1 for gamemodes 2 for class editor (class editor not yet made coming soon)" << endl;                           
        system("pause>nul");
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
    {
        gamemodes();
    }
    return 0;
}

int gamemodes()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "pick a gamemode" << endl;
    cout << "1 for team death match" << endl;
    cout << "rest coming soon!!!!" << endl;
    system("pause>nul");
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
    {
        map_picker();
    }
    return 0;
}

int map_picker()
{
    while (go = true)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "pick a map" << endl;
        cout << "1 for town" << endl;
        system("pause>nul");
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
        {
            town_load();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

int town_load() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```